# Why does this printf statement, or lack there of, alter the effect of the for loop?

Tags: c, cs50

First section of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string name = GetString();
    int n = strlen(name);
    int j = 0;
    int c = 0;
    char initials[j];    
    char input[c];
    char space[] = {' '};

    for (int i = 0, c = 0; i < n; i++, c++)
    {        
        input[c] = name[i];

        printf("%c, %c\n", name[i], input[c]);     
    }
```

Problem area:

```
    printf("%d\n", n);
    for (int i = 0, c = 0; i < n; i++, c++)
    {                 
        if (input[c] != space[0])
        {
            initials[j] = input[c];
            j++;
            break;
        }
        printf("loop test\n");
    }

    j = 0;

    printf("%c\n", initials[j]);      
}
```

If my input is:

```
     hello
```

Then my output is what I want (loop test == number of spaces before input):

```
loop test
loop test
loop test
loop test
loop test
h
```

Unless, I remove:

```
printf("%d\n", n);
```

Then if my input starts with >= 4 spaces, my output is:

```
loop test
loop test
loop test
loop test
// blank line
// blank line
```

the two comments are actual blank lines in the output

*Sorry for some of the erroneous printf statements, I was trying to identify the bug.

Comment: While it's not an error, you've got a variable named `c` at the function scope, and then a different variable also named `c` inside each for loop. This will likely be confusing later when you want to change or expand the code. I'd recommend using longer, more descriptive names for your variables.

Comment: @user1118321 Okay, I was under the impression that I was just recalling that same variable. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One major problem is here:

```
int c = 0;
 ...
char input[c];
```

`input[]` is made a zero length array.  Then the code merrily writes beyond the end of it which amounts to random writing on other parts of the stack frame.

The fix is to properly size the array before writing into it.

There is also

```
int j = 0;
 ...
char initials[j];
```

Comment: How do I properly size it, if I don't know the length?

Comment: @Jord:  There are several strategies.  The "old school" approach is to make it bigger than will ever be needed (`1000`?).  Another approach is to calculate how big it needs to be (maybe `len+1`?).  Another approach is to guess at some length and if it becomes too small, expand it (which doesn't easily apply to this particular code).

Comment: @Jord: How to size the initials array?  You know that the string is N characters long, and there can't be more than (N+1)/2 characters that are initials (given `a b c`, length 5, there are (5+1)/2 = 3 initials), so you have an upper bound on the length of the array (but don't forget to allow for a trailing null byte).

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something more like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  string name = GetString();
  int n = strlen(name);
  int j = 0;
  int c = 0;
  char *initials = calloc(n,1);    
  char *input = calloc(n,1);

  for (int i = 0, c = 0; i < n; i++, c++)
  {        
    input[c] = name[i];

    printf("%c, %c\n", name[i], input[c]);     
  } 

  printf("%d\n", n);
  for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) // you weren't using i in the loop
  {                 
    if (input[c] != ' ')
    {
        initials[j] = input[c];
        j++;
        break;
    }
    printf("loop test\n");
  }

  j = 0;

  printf("%c\n", initials[j]);      

  free(initials);
  free(input);
}
```